# Proper way to convert an Enhanced Metafile to a Windows Metafile without pixel rounding

Tags: winapi, metafile

When I convert an Enhanced Metafile (constructed via GDI+ in C#) into an old-style Windows Metafile, the results are very rough, apparently because coordinates are being rounded to the nearest screen pixel.  I see this if I convert either via

GetWinMetaFileBits(emfh, bits_l, bits, MM_ANISOTROPIC, GetDC(0));

or using GDI+'s Metafile::EmfToWmfBits.  The culprit is presumably the screen DC being used.  [This posting](http://www.powerbasic.com/support/pbforums/showthread.php?t=21530) suggests using a printer DC, which works for me, but obviously will not work if the user has no printers installed.  Is there a better way?  I have considered creating a high-resolution in-memory DC for the purpose, but I can find no proper documentation for doing so, and I also worry about the RAM used.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way is to create a much higher resolution memory DC, render to that and then save it however you want. Note that font sizes can get screwed up by this.

```
 HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC ( hDC );
 HBITMAP memBM = CreateCompatibleBitmap ( hDC, nWidth, nHeight );
 SelectObject ( memDC, memBM );
```

With nWidth , nHeight much larger.
The CreateCompatible bit should set all the dpi etc, but I have had problems where the fonts were drawn fixed pixel size rather than rescaled - so they ended up being only 10pixels high on a 10,000 pixel image

Comment: Yes, but how do I create a much higher resolution memory DC?  Can you point at any documentation?

Comment: I can use CreateCompatibleBitmap() to create a bitmap with very many pixels, but it will have the same DPI as the screen, and thus my metafile will get drawn in the upper-left corner, with the same problems as before.  Perhaps if I exagerate the size of the drawing area when creating the original Enhanced Metafile then I can get it to use more of the bitmap while doing the conversion.  Is this what you mean?  How are fonts screwed up by this process?

Comment: CreateEnhMetafile is the appropriate API for this

Answer (score 0):

Ask Google for ENMETA.EXE

Description by Microsoft

Example in download included.

Comment: Ah, you will use it for Your SPPS clone.

Comment: Coiche placeable metafiles for best results. Sometime it's useful to add 0.1 mm on the right side and the bottom. Some programs cut these by inserting the wmf graphic.

Comment: ENMETA's code that converts enhanced metafiles to Windows metafiles uses the screen DC (GetDC(NULL)) and thus will suffer from the problem I originally described.  Yes, it's for Q, which *is* a competitor to SPSS, but hardly a clone.  Perhaps you want PSPP?